# Problema en ubuntu con require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Changes/Modelo/DataObj.php');

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache, server

estoy haciendo una web con php y mysql . EL problema que tengo es que la hago en windows con xamp y luego la subo a git para despues clonar el proyecto en un server ubuntu 16.
En windows funciona bien pero cuando la pruebo en ubuntu el servidor me dice:

```
 127.0.0.1:54516 [500]: /Vista/index.php - require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/Changes/Changes/Modelo/DataObj.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/Changes/Vista/index.php on line 3
```

He estado viendo en internet y en varios sitios dicen que primero se ponga :

```
require_once ( 'db/config.php');
```

Pero a mi no me ha funcionado. ¿Alguna idea lo que estaría pasando?

Comment: cual es el resultado de correr esto en el terminal? Lo puedes agregar a la pregunta: `ls -l /var/www/Changes/Changes/Modelo/DataObj.php`

Comment: Buenos días eftshift, gracias por responder. Bueno creo que lo he solucionado pero a medias. Lo que he hecho es quitar un /Changes de la url, quedando asi:  echo require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/Modelo/DataObj.php'); Como ves he puesto un eco delante para ver que hacia y responde con un 1 ademas en la consola de Netbeans ha desaparecido este error. SI pongo lo que tú dices también es OK : -rwxrwxr-x 1 carlos root 1737 oct  1 20:43 /var/www/Changes/Modelo/DataObj.php.

Comment: Lo que no se es por que tengo que quitar un /Changes si en mi VirtaulHost en DocumentRoot es: \var\www y luego en la carpeta www esta la carpeta Changes. Ahora tengo el problema de  Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
Done. Ese si que no me habia pasado en la vida. Si pongo sudo netstat -plnt este responde: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR    4443/php . Aquí si que ya me he quedado parado. No se si es por que Apache esta funcionando por el puerto 8080 y tengo que modificar algo en la configuración del PHP.

Comment: La verdad que esta solución no me gusta nada. Ya que me he dado cuenta la variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] funciona distinto en windows que php.

Comment: La verdad que esta solución no me gusta nada. Ya que me he dado cuenta la variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] funciona distinto en windows que en ubuntu. En windows es C:/xamp/htdocs mientras que en ubuntu llega al directorio raiz de la web, ahi esta mi problema. ¿Como podría hacerlo para que funcionara en windows y ubuntu?